# prolog affectation problems

Tags: javascript, variables, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a problem with prolog variable affectation, I guess.
I verify a condition  using javascript code! if true, a javascript code gets a value.

```
if (k<12){
    Case=2;
}
```

after, this variable is assigned to a prolog variable. in the knowledge base if the condition is verified, a response is generated.

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    <?,  Gu is Case ,?>
    <?, anomalie(Gu,Comment0) ,?>
    var v= "<?, write(Comment0) ,?>";//Get the response 
    document.write(v);// displaying the response 

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: @lurker can you help me?

Comment: @lurker can you help me?